# Lookup/Find strings within a list of lists, and then return the list's name

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a list of lists, like this example. For reference, my data has 300 lists each with around 90 components each, but of unequal length which is why it must stay in a list (I believe)

```
a <- list("FRUITS" = c("apples","bananas","pears"),
          "VEGGIES" = c("lettuce","pepper","carrot"),
          "BREADS" = c("bagel","muffin","sandwhich"))
```

and a dataframe that looks like this but has thousands of rows

```
b <- data.frame("Sample" = c("BB","TT","LT"),
        "Food" = c("SandWich","Tomato","BANANA"),
        "Volume" = c(124,1356,1343))
```

My goal is for my dataframe to mutate a new column that contains the list name that each Food item resides in. This is where Lookup/Finding strings within a list of lists and returning the list's name comes from.

```
data.frame("Sample" = c("BB","TT","LT"),
        "Food" = c("SandWich","Tomato","BANANA"),
        "Volume" = c(124,1356,1343),
        "Match" = c("BREADS","VEGGIES","FRUITS")
```

How can I do this? I have tried using other techniques on stack that around similar to Excel's VLOOKUP but no other threads are returning the lists' name from what I can tell.

Thanks for any help or feedback.

Edit: Case sensitivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`

```
transform(merge(b, stack(a), by.x = c("Food"), by.y = "values"),
    Food = ind, ind = NULL)
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
enframe(a, value = "Food") %>%
  unnest(Food) %>% 
  right_join(b, by = "Food") %>%
  mutate(Food = coalesce(name, Food), name = NULL)
```

If we need to change the case

```
library(purrr)
map(a, toupper) %>% 
  enframe(value = "Food") %>%
  unnest(Food) %>%
  right_join(b %>% 
     mutate(Food = toupper(Food)), by = "Food") %>% 
  mutate(Food = coalesce(name, Food), name = NULL)
```

Comment: Now that I learn about transform, yeah the ideal way for my end result would be to mutate the new column that is equivalent to the list name of the food type/matched list name.  However I am not getting any results from this

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it non case-sensitive? For example, "Sanwhich", "SandWhich" all get treated as "sandwhich?" The key here is I do not want to change the original data, but perform the search non-case sensitive.